# nginx Redirect specific subdomain and path

Tags: nginx, redirect

Our nginx config serves multiple sites with their own subdomains.

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  server_name ~^(?P<sub>.+)\.(example1|example2)\.com$;
  root /var/www/instances/$sub;

  ...
}
```

I want to redirect one specific subdomain with its path to different sites, but I cannot figure out how to write the check. I need to check for the host part and then check for the path to decide where the redirect should land.

The map looks somehting like this:

| Old URI | New URI |
| --- | --- |
| `sub1.example1.com/wiki/0/$path` | `newSub1.example1.com/wiki/0/$path` |
| `sub1.example1.com/wiki/20/$path` | `newSub2.example1.com/wiki/0/$path` |

*Where `$path` is simply the rest of the request URI*

All other requests to `sub1.example1.com` should work as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution is to split `sub1.example1.com` into a separate `server` block. As you will see from [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) a `server_name` with an exact name always takes precedence over a `server_name` with a regular expression.

This means that there are two `server` blocks with near identical contents, but this can be mitigated by using [the `include` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include).

---

Alternatively, you can test the value of `$host$request_uri` using [a `map` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map). *This is less efficient, as you will be testing the URL in every site.*

For example:

```
map $host$request_uri $redirect {
    default 0;
    ~*^sub1.example1.com/wiki/0/(?<path>.*)$ //newSub1.example1.com/wiki/0/$path;
    ~*^sub1.example1.com/wiki/20/(?<path>.*)$ //newSub2.example1.com/wiki/0/$path;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name ~^(?P<sub>.+)\.(example1|example2)\.com$;
    root /var/www/instances/$sub;
    if ($redirect) { return 301 $scheme:$redirect; }

    ...
}
```

Comment: thx for the tip. I will try using a second `server` block